# Why does Git tracks only some directories with ./ prefix from .gitignore?

Tags: git, directory, gitignore

I'm used to using `./` prefix for directories, which is why I've created such a `.gitignore` file:

```
./test1/
./test2/
./test3/
./bin/
```

However, it was not working properly, and I spent a lot of time trying to remove the first three directories from `git status` output (only `./bin` was not listed out).

```
$ git status
On branch nowe
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        test1/
        test2/
        test3/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Then, I came up with an idea to remove the `./` prefix from `.gitignore` file and it worked:

```
$ git status
On branch nowe
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   .gitignore

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Removing / restoring the `./` prefix for `./bin` folder changes nothing.

This situation seems to be unusual and illogical. Why does it happen?

Comment: Why did you use `./` prefix in the `.gitignore` in the first place and not just leave it out from the start on?

Comment: Note that adding a pattern to the `.gitignore` after staging doesn't remove any files from git.

Comment: @dan1st Why not? As I said I'm used to using the prefix.

Comment: When does the staging process occur? I copied all 4 directories to the project with the directories' names already in `.gitignore` file and run only `git status`. Then, I removed every `./` and run `git status` again.

Comment: Staging refers to the process of executing the `git add` command (or similar). And nobody tells git to respect `./` in the `.gitignore`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but I was not using `git add` after adding the files to the project. Also, I get git cannot respect the `./`, but why does it respect it for the `bin/` directory? Why isn't it consistent? And, why wouldn't it respect quite standard way of defining paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, prefixing with `./` is not valid in .gitignore. For the observation with `bin` directory, I cannot reproduce it:

```
§ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .gitignore
    bin/
    test1/
    test2/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
§ cat .gitignore 
./test1/
./test2/
./bin/
```

Most likely your `bin` directory is empty, and therefore it does not appear in `git status`. Git does not track empty directories.

Comment: None of the directories are empty, I've thought about this. I've just tried to clean cache `git rm --cached -r`, `git update-index --assume-unchanged` but it changed nothing.

Comment: Also interesting is *PyCharm* doesn't care for `./` and marks it as directory.

Comment: Maybe that was cache problem - I moved the directories out of the project, changed their names, pasted them back and *Git* works as you said - ignores paths with the `./` prefix.